# Input from talend into tsystem python script

Tags: python, talend

I have some csv files which i read using tfiledelimited component and want to pass those rows along into python script on tsystem component for some manipulations.

I have connected the output from tfiledelimited into tsystem and have set the schema but how to read those columns from csv reader into python script , please help..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dummy shell wrapper and call python script inside that. Make sure proper python instance is available on host executing the script and accesible (/bin/python) and PATH is resolving to this directory.

And call that wrapper from tSystem.